# SQL query VBA Access issue

Tags: ms-access

I get an error when I try to execute this code, I think I have a problem in the sql query and the line `"Service = Dlookup ..."` can you help please ! thank you very much

```
    Private Sub btnConnexion_Click()

    Dim Categ As Integer
    Dim Service As String
    Dim IdProf As Integer

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb


    'vérification que l'utilisater a bien entrer e login et le mot de passe
    Me.txtlogin.SetFocus
    If IsNull(Me.txtlogin) Then
    MsgBox "svp entrer votre login ", vbInformation, "login required "
    Me.txtlogin.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtmdp) Then
    MsgBox "svp entrer votre mots de passe ", vbInformation, "mdp required "
    Me.txtmdp.SetFocus
    Else
    'vérification que le login et le mdp sont corrects
    If (IsNull(DLookup("login", "dbo_Authentification", "login='" & Me.txtlogin.Value &       "'"))) Or _
        (IsNull(DLookup("mdp", "dbo_Authentification", "mdp='" & Me.txtmdp.Value & "'")))    Then
        MsgBox "login ou mdp incorrect"
    Else
    'récupération de l'IdCatégorie dans Categ, pour préciser les sessions des acteurs selon   leurs catégories professionneles
        Categ = DLookup("IdCategorie", "dbo_Professionnel", "IdProfessionnel = " &   DLookup("IdCompte", "dbo_Authentification", "login='" & Me.txtlogin.Value & "'"))
        'DoCmd.Close
        If Categ = 3 Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "role"
            Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "ListingPatients"

            'Service récupère le service du professionnel authentifié pour l'afficher à   l'entete du formulaire "ListingPatients"
            Service = DLookup("IntituleServ", "dbo_Service", "IdService = " &   DLookup("IdProfessionnel", "dbo_Professionnel", "IdProfessionnel = " & DLookup("IdCompte",   "dbo_Authentification", "login='" & Me.txtlogin.Value & "'")))
            Forms![ListingPatients]![txtIntituleServ] = Service



            strSQL = "SELECT dbo_Patient.*, dbo_Service.IntituleServ, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.lit, dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie FROM dbo_Service INNER JOIN ((dbo_Professionnel INNER JOIN dbo_Authentification ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_Authentification.IdCompte) INNER JOIN (dbo_Patient INNER JOIN (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle INNER JOIN dbo_DonneePatientActuelles ON dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdHosp = dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdHosp) ON dbo_Patient.IdPatient = dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdPatient) ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdProfessionnel) ON dbo_Service.IdService = dbo_Professionnel.Idservice WHERE (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree)<=Now()) AND ((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie)>Now())) OR (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie) Is Null) AND dbo_Service.IntituleServ = '" & Service & "') ;"

       End If
    End If
   End If


   End Sub
```

So when I execute this code I get the error "Invalid use of null" in the line "Service = ..." and the sql query dosen't return the condition when ! thank you very very much

---

So, after adding the Nz, I think that the problem of Null is solved

```
           Service = Nz(DLookup("IntituleServ", "dbo_Service", "IdService = " & DLookup("IdService", "dbo_Professionnel", "IdProfessionnel = " & DLookup("IdCompte", "dbo_Authentification", "login='" & Me.txtlogin.Value & "'"))), "inconnu")
        Forms![ListingPatients]![txtIntituleServ] = Service
```

But I still have an issue with the SQL query, I think I didn't put the correct syntax of SQL query integrating in the VBA code, can you take a look to this line :

```
        strSQL = "SELECT dbo_Patient.*, dbo_Service.IntituleServ, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.lit, dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree, dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie FROM dbo_Service INNER JOIN ((dbo_Professionnel INNER JOIN dbo_Authentification ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_Authentification.IdCompte) INNER JOIN (dbo_Patient INNER JOIN (dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle INNER JOIN dbo_DonneePatientActuelles ON dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdHosp = dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdHosp) ON dbo_Patient.IdPatient = dbo_DonneePatientActuelles.IdPatient) ON dbo_Professionnel.IdProfessionnel = dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.IdProfessionnel) ON dbo_Service.IdService = dbo_Professionnel.Idservice WHERE (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateEntree)<=Now()) AND ((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie)>Now())) OR (((dbo_HospitalisatAcuelle.DateSortie) Is Null)) ;"
        strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE [dbo_Service]![IntituleServ] = ' " & Service & " ' "
DoCmd.OpenQuery(strSQL)
```

Thank you,

Comment: I recommend that you don't attempt to nest three DLOOKUP functions like this. Split across three lines (at least) and it will be easier for you to debug. At the very least, you will be able to discover which one of the three calls is causing a problem.

Comment: In response to your edit, you have put a semicolon at the end of the first `strSQL =` instead of at the end of the query. (In fact, the semicolon is not essential for Access.)

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `Service` as a string variable.
`DLookup` returns Null if no matching record is found. A Null cannot be stored in a String, but can be stored in a Variant.

So either use `Dim Service As Variant` and test with `IsNull()`

or use `Service = Nz(DLookup(...), "Inconnu")` to return "Inconnu" if Dlookup() fails.